# Print current page multiple times with different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing

I have a react-app that populates the page dynamically based on a selected job number and date (from an array).

[image: Filter criteria]

Is it possible to print the current page for the selected job and ALL its date ranges?

The ideal function would look like this I guess:

```
function printAllDates(){
   const index = this.state.datesList.indexOf(this.state.selectedDate)
   this.state.datesList.forEach(date => {
      window.print();
      this.setState({ selectedDate: this.state.datesList[(index + 1)]})
   })
}
```

This above function works in the sense that it adds print previews to a queue but the data on the print preview doesn't change.

Comment: Whatever you want to change in React must have some piece of "state" attached to it. So, whenever you change this state, the UI will react accordingly. But, you have to have this info attached to the Component that should react.

Comment: @MarkSkayff Changing this.state.selectedDate updates the page data with componentDidUpdate. So the function provided works, but window.print() doesn't wait for setState to finish.